# RavenDB MapReduce Reduce or aggregate MapReduce results serverside

Tags: mapreduce, ravendb, aggregate

Quite often I end up in a situation where I want to reduce the MapReduce. For instance if I have two objects from which I want to get the Version from one object, and the Count from another.

```
public class Visit {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }
}

public class Search {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string VisitId { get; set; }
}

public class MapReduceResult {
    public string VisitId { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

When reducing I would have to group the Visit and Search together by the Id and Version to be able to get the number of searches per Version. Unfortunately there would be one row for every single visit, and we are talking millions of those. Pulling the data over to client side is therefore not the preferred way to go, and also the 1024 object limit kinda messes that up too.

This problem would be solved if I somehow could Reduce the MapReduce again. Then I'd just group by Version the second time, completely ignoring the VisitId, and sum up all the counts. Is there any way of doing this?

Not even Sum works on a queryable, so it feels like I've run out of serverside options.

Do you guys have any idea, do I make any sense at all?

Answer (score 0):

Since release 2.0 of RavenDB a new feature has been added which lets you index related documents:

http://ravendb.net/docs/2.0/client-api/querying/static-indexes/indexing-related-documents

In your case the index would look like:

```
public class Index : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Search, Index.Result>
{
    public class Result
    {
        public string Version { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }
    }

    public Index()
    {
        Map = searches => from search in searches
                          let visit = LoadDocument<Visit>(search.VisitId)
                          select new Result
                                     {
                                         Version = visit.Version,
                                         Count = 1
                                     };

        Reduce = results => from result in results
                            group result by result.Version
                            into g
                            select new Result
                                       {
                                           Version = g.Key,
                                           Count = g.Sum(x => x.Count)
                                       };
    }
}
```